# Performing 1d convolution using 2d kernel in keras

Tags: python, machine-learning, neural-network, keras, conv-neural-network

I am currently working on a CNN network, in which i want to apply a 2d kernel on a image, but it only has to perform 1d convolution, meaning that it only has to move along one axis (x-axis in this case).

The shape of the kernel is same as the y-axis of the image. The number of filters applied is not a concern at the moment.

An example: 
Given a image of size (6,3,3) = (rows, cols,  color_channel)

How should i perform a 1d convolution given a 2d filter?

Tried what was suggested by @Marcin Możejko

```
dim_x = 3
dim_y = 6
color_channels = 3
#model.add(ZeroPadding2D((6,4),input_shape=(6,3,3)))
model.add(Conv2D(filters = 32,kernel_size=(dim_y,1) , activation='linear' , input_shape = (6,3,3)))
print model.output_shape
model.add(Reshape((dim_x,color_channels)))
```

Error:

```
The total size of the new array must be unchanged
```

Comment: What would be the shape of one sample when it gets in the conv layer? What would be the shape of the kernel? what do you expect as output? From that we can help you, otherwise this is too vague

Comment: I tried to add  bit more info on how i which it would perform.. hopes it clarifies stuff..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming that your image `shape=(dim_x, dim_y, img_channels)` you can obtain a `1D` convolution by setting:

```
conv1d_on_image = Convolution2D(output_channels, 1, dim_y, border_mode='valid')(input)
```

Remember that the output from this layer would have shape `(dim_x, 1, output_channels)`. If you want your input to be sequential you may use the `Reshape` layer by setting:

```
conv1d_on_image = Reshape((dim_x, output_channels))(conv1d_on_image)
```

This would produce output with shape `(dim_x, output_channels)`.

An interesting fact is that this is exactly the way how `Conv1D` works in `Keras` with `tf` backend.

Comment: I am getting an error message stating that the total size of the new array must be unchanged.. I will change my question to add example.

Comment: Weird. Could you provide a full code and the line which produces error? Have you switched to `Keras 2.0`?

Comment: Yes.. I have switched to keras 2.0