# How to perform 1d convolution using 2d kernel

Tags: python, keras, conv-neural-network

I a currently trying to perform a 1d convolution on a image using a 2d kernel. The 1d convolution should be performed across the X-axis of the image, the images are spectograms of audio files.  The image in which the convolution in performed is divided in to 13 section, each section centers around a center frequency, in which 13 different CNN network will perform 1d convolution to extract in total (x,13) feature points, and individually (x,1) feature points. x is given by the length of `data_output_train`

The kernel size is defined as such the center element will be the center frequency.

This is how the data is currently stored:

```
def model(feature,train_input_data,
        train_output_data,
        test_input_data,
        test_output_data):

        #Feature number 0-12
        number_of_filters = 1
        #Debug stuff!
        print feature
        print center_freq[feature]
        print center_freq[feature]*2
        print int(center_freq[feature]*2)
        print frequency_to_pixel_row(int(center_freq[feature]*2))

        col = int(frequency_to_pixel_row(int(center_freq[feature]*2)))
        #init Data containers
        data_train_input = []
        data_test_input = []
        data_train_output = []
        data_test_output = []
        print "jghkjhk"

        #Extract the desired section
        for images in train_input_data:
            if feature == 0:
                #print images.shape[0]
                data_train_input = images[images.shape[0] - int(center_freq[feature]*2):images.shape[0],:]
                #print data.shape
        #Vstack so it can be used in keras
        data_train_input_vstack = np.vstack(data_train_input)

        #Extract the desired section
        for images in test_input_data:
            if feature == 0:
                #print images.shape[0]
                data_test_input = images[images.shape[0] - int(center_freq[feature]*2):images.shape[0],:]
                #print data.shape
        data_test_input_vstack = np.vstack(data_test_input)

        #Extract the desired output data
        for rows in train_output_data:
            #print rows.shape
            data_train_output = rows[:,feature]
        data_train_output_vstack = np.vstack(data_train_output)

        #Extract the desired output data
        for rows in test_output_data:
            #print rows.shape
            data_test_output = rows[:,feature]
        data_test_output_vstack = np.vstack(data_test_output)
```

Now i need to define the network structure such that it performs the 1d convolution.. But how do i ensure it also does that? and performs the way i want it to do.. I guess i have to use convolution2d, but how do i fix it to only perform 1d convoulution?

Comment: Check out this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42618543/performing-1d-convolution-using-2d-kernel-in-keras

Comment: I have 3 dimension.. X,y, color.